# What kind of bathroom/kitchen flooring works over a wood subfloor?

Tags: bathroom, flooring, tile

...and how to install it?

I have an older (1930s) home built over a crawl space with wood subflooring and hardwood floors. There is some settlement but it's not objectionable. The kitchen and bathrooms currently have sheet vinyl over the hardwood, and it's in need of replacement. I'd like to go back with VCT or possibly even ceramic tile, but I'm concerned about cracking and long-term durability. I will be doing the work myself, so any advice or links to information/education as to how to do the installation properly will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

LVT or luxury vinyl tile or planks has many advantages over VCT and ceramic.
It is perfect for kitchens and baths.
1- It's waterproof.
2- It can be installed over your vinyl floor.
3- It requires no mastic or thin set or grout.
4- It can be scored and snapped to cut. No special tools are needed.
5- It requires very little maintenance. ( Occasional damp mopping)
6- Most of the products come with it own padding and needs no vapor barrier.
7- It need no acclimation period.
There are many selections. I advise getting a product with a minimum thickness of 5mm. Cost may be a little higher, however you do not need other products to install the floor and maintenance is almost nil.

Comment: This is what the OP should do. Doing tile right is a twelve page process. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51861/how-do-i-correctly-install-ceramic-floor-tile

Answer (score 0):

Recommended method to install tiles over wooden floors would be

to use backer boards also known as cement board, that are made for that application.

They are extremely hard and wont flex.

Tiles will not crack on backer boards if there is floor movement.

The instalation is simple.

You use special screws for backer boards and screw them on the wood floor.

Comment: Simple, sure. But it's a lot of work on your knees, with a lot of tools they're unlikely to own or never use again, and if they've never done it before it's highly likely one or more of the steps will be done wrong which screws the whole thing up. *use backer board* (step three of twelve), provided the subfloor is the required thickness (minimum 5/8") and in good repair. Otherwise start over, "from subfloor-less 16"oc joists".